# building R from source: make error 1

Tags: r, unix, makefile

I am trying to build R from source in a directory that I have read,write exec access (on unix server). I've tried googling about for this particular error and searching SO to no avail. I feel it is something daft.

I have unpacked the source (R-3.0.2) changed to that directory `/home/rmgzshd/R-3.0.2` and run `./configure --prefix=$HOME/R-3.0.2` successfully (I think) and I have the dependencies required, e.g. the ./configure messages end with:

```
R is now configured for x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
  Source directory:          .
  Installation directory:    /home/rmgzshd/R-3.0.2
  C compiler:                gcc -std=gnu99  -g -O2
  Fortran 77 compiler:       gfortran  -g -O2
  C++ compiler:              g++  -g -O2
  Fortran 90/95 compiler:    gfortran -g -O2
  Obj-C compiler:
  Interfaces supported:      X11
  External libraries:        readline
  Additional capabilities:   PNG, JPEG, NLS
  Options enabled:           shared BLAS, R profiling
  Recommended packages:      yes
```

and I seem to have the correct directory structure and Makefiles in the same `./configure` directory:

```
ChangeLog      configure     etc      m4           Makefile.bak  Makefrag.cc_lo  NEWS.0    po      SVN-REVISION  VERSION-NICK
config.log     configure.ac  INSTALL  Makeconf     Makefile.fw   Makefrag.cxx    NEWS.1    README  tests
config.site    COPYING       lib64    Makeconf.in  Makefile.in   Makefrag.m      NEWS.2    share   tools
config.status  doc           libtool  Makefile     Makefrag.cc   NEWS            NEWS.pdf  src     VERSION
```

However the `make` command is failing with a message that seems just wrong...(as m4 exists)

`/bin/sh: line 1: cd: m4: No such file or directory`

I have also tried just a simpler `./configure` without the `--prefix` followed by `make` but that makes my Installation directory `/usr/bin` and fails with the same error.

Has anyone come across this problem? Should Source directory: be `.` for instance?

thx

**EDIT** following the suggestion below I tried `make distclean` but clearly the paths are borked somehow, and despite what the `./configure` message says as I get:

```
make distclean
/bin/sh: line 1: cd: tests: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: line 1: cd: src: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: line 1: cd: share: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: line 1: cd: etc: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: line 1: cd: doc: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: line 1: cd: tools: No such file or directory
/bin/sh: line 1: cd: m4: No such file or directory
```

but they are all there in `/home/rmgzshd/R-3.0.2` where I execute the command...

Comment: Weird things sometimes happen when I play with different options to `configure`, several times, in the same directory: the directory ends up containing inconsistent bits of those different attempts. You can try to clean the directory by typing `make distclean`, and then `./configure --prefix=$HOME/R-3.0.2 && make`.

Comment: @Vincent Zoonekynd thx will try...

Comment: I wouldn't try to install in the same folder as the source. Make a new, empty folder somewhere - `mkdir $HOME/build/R` and then from a clean unpack of the R sources do `./configure --prefix=$HOME/build/R`.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this exactly same problem by changing the value of `CDPATH` from `CDPATH=/some/location` to `CDPATH=`.
Alternatively if you need to retain the value in the `CDPATH`, simply add `.` to it `CDPATH=.:/some/location`.

If you want to read more about this behaviour, visit https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112363/is-cdpath-behavior-broken-in-bourne-shell-bin-sh